# Splitting an integral with absolute value.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is $\log(c)$ the value for which this integral minimum is, I mean should I integrate from $0$ to $\log(c)$ and then $\log(c)$ to 1? ${\large\int} ^{1}_{0} |e^x - c| \; dx $ here $c ∈ [1, e].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know when $e^x-c$ is positive and negative.  It will be positive when $e^x>c$ which is when $x>\log c.$  If $x<\log c$ then $e^x-c$ is negative and then $|e^x-c| = c-e^x$.  So you're right in splitting the integral at $x=\log c$.  But you need to get the signs right.

$$\int_0^{\log c} c-e^x \; dx + \int_{\log c}^{1} e^x-c \; dx.$$

Comment: is it Log(c) or ln(c)?

Comment: It's natural log.  People use different notations for it.